# Create single dynamic query to get tables data based on funcion call in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I want to create a dynamic query to get tables data. Using this dynamic query we need to select all columns or needed columns. Need dynamically Joins, where condition also.

Answer (score 0):

We can able to create a single dynamic SELECT query in coldfusion. Below I have added a CFC function, this is having the dynamic query. Please check it.

```
<cffunction name="select" access="public" returntype="Query">
        <cfargument name="tableName" type="string" required="true">
        <cfargument name="joinType" type="array" required="false">
        <cfargument name="conditionType" type="array" required="false">
        <cfargument name="subQuery" type="array" required="false">
        <cfargument name="orderBy" type="string" required="false">
        <cfargument name="groupBy" type="string" required="false">
        <cfargument name="neededColumns" type="string" required="false">

        <cfquery name="selectQ">
            SELECT
                <cfif len(arguments.neededColumns)>
                    #arguments.neededColumns#
                <cfelse>
                    *
                </cfif>
                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments, "subQuery")>
                    <cfloop array="#arguments.subQuery#" index="i">
                        ,#PreserveSingleQuotes(i)#
                    </cfloop>
                </cfif>
            FROM
                #arguments.tableName#
                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments, "joinType") AND !ArrayIsEmpty(arguments.joinType)>
                    <cfloop array="#arguments.joinType#" index="i">
                        #i.type# JOIN #i.table# #i.alias# ON #i.primaryColumn# = #i.alias#.#i.secondaryColumn#
                    </cfloop>
                </cfif>
            WHERE 1=1
                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments, "conditionType") AND !ArrayIsEmpty(arguments.conditionType)>
                    <cfloop array="#arguments.conditionType#" index="i">
                        AND #i.column#
                        <cfif structKeyExists(i, "symbol")>
                            #i.symbol#
                        <cfelse>
                            =
                        </cfif>
                        <cfif isNumeric(i.value)>
                            <cfqueryparam value="#i.value#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                        <cfelseif isDate(i.value)>
                            <cfqueryparam value="#i.value#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
                        <cfelse>
                            <cfqueryparam value="#i.value#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                        </cfif>
                    </cfloop>
                </cfif>
                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments, "groupBy") AND len(arguments.groupBy)>
                    GROUP BY #arguments.groupBy#
                </cfif>
                <cfif structKeyExists(arguments, "orderBy") AND len(arguments.orderBy)>
                    #arguments.orderBy#
                </cfif>
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn selectQ>
    </cffunction>
```

Below code explains how to call this above function and how to sent the arguments to this function.

```
<cfset getAllDatas = application.base.get(
        tableName = "Users U",
        joinType = [
          {"table" : "customers", "type" : "INNER", "alias" : "C", "primaryColumn" : "U.user_id" , "secondaryColumn" : "userid"},
          {"table" : "customerType", "type" : "INNER", "alias" : "CT", "primaryColumn" : "C.eventid" , "secondaryColumn" : "eventid"}
        ],
        subQuery = [
          "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Participants WHERE UserID = #session.UserID# AND status = 'attended') AS count"
        ],
        orderBy  = " ORDER BY C.CreatedDate DESC",
        groupBy  = "C.CreatedDate",
        conditionType = [
          { "column" : "UserID", "value" : session.userID},
          { "column" : "C.status", "value" : "Attended"}
        ]
 )/>
```

Guys, If you have any ideas, please share with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a public function that allows all sorts of input into a query. Make sure you sanitize and validate the inputs before putting them in the SQL string. This is ripe for some injection.

Comment: An open query like this will also severely impact database performance. And is this completely dynamic query necessary? How many different queries will you be working with? It's rarely a safe idea to allow this much freedom in talking to your database. For Instance: "`<cfset getAllDatas = application.base.get(tableName = "Users")>` and I just queried your entire `Users` table. Or I could query system tables and get a complete structure of your database to further use to get all of your data. Mainly, is the risk worth the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You said need to validate the string arguments before putting the SQL query. Okay. I accept. If we pass empty string in tableName.It's throwing error. So, If we pass empty string means, i will use check if it's not empty, may be if empty means, i will use default tableName. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I need to working more than 30 tables. And each table having different table joins. So, Hope, I need to write more functions. So, I have choose dynamic query. And If we select users table all records means, we just pass tableName only. "Like as `<cfset getAllDatas = application.baseService.select(tableName =  "Users")>`. If we need to take the users table data using condition means, just use "`<cfset getAllDatas = application.baseService.select(tableName = "Users", conditionType = [{ "column" : "UserID", "value" : session.userID}])/>`" .

Comment: By validate, I mean more than just checking if it's empty to prevent errors. I mean you need to check the input to determine if it's allowable and safe. And if you have 30 tables, then you already know at least one list to validate the `tableName` argument against. A whitelist will prevent people from querying tables you don't want them to. And I'm not sure you understood what I was saying about passing values to this dynamic query. The way it's written, if all you pass to your public function is  `tableName='Users'`, then the query will return the entire `Users` table. Probably not good.

Comment: 30 tables isn't really a lot. And I would guess that your application would know what data it plans to need. Writing out the specific queries you need will make this much more secure. It may seem like it will be easier to use a dynamic query like this, but it is opening your application to all sorts of potential headaches. I would still highly discourage using an open query like this that allows anyone to query anything in your database that they want.